# Encrypt in Android and Decrypt in NodeJS (Asymmetric Encryption)

Tags: android, node.js, public-key-encryption

How to Encrypt in Android and Decrypt in NodeJS (Asymmetric Encryption)

I want to Send Encrypted String from android and Decrypt in NodeJS using Asymmetric Encryption

Comment: That is a pretty broad question (possibly even close vote worthy) - have you even tried googling it? Do you have any code you have written that attempts it, but fails to work?

Comment: Why asymmetric encryption?